# isset from form working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, html, forms

I have came up with this problem which is that the isset (button) from a form works on a localhost but not in a server, I have been searching a lot about this but couldn't find a answer that fits my problem.

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
include ('dbconnect.php');

if(isset($_POST['revertbtn'])){
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }else{...}?>
```

the code simply doesn't get past the isset verification, I have done some echo's inside the code to see where the problem was, and after that isset, the code just dies, doesn't even get into the db connection.

The code with the button name from the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="adminrevertbackend.php">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Amount of JC Token</th>
                <th>Situation</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="myTable">
            <?php
            $get_historic_query = "SELECT * FROM consult";
            $get_historic_result = mysqli_query($db, $get_historic_query);
            while ($get_historic = mysqli_fetch_array($get_historic_result)) {
                echo '<tr>
                  <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="consultID[]" value="' . $get_historic['consultID'] . '"></td>
                  <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="consultUsername[]" value="' . $get_historic['consultUsername'] . '"></td>
                  <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="consultDescription[]" value="' . $get_historic['consultDescription'] . '"></td>
                  <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="consultAmount[]" value="' . $get_historic['consultAmount'] . '"></td>
                  <td>' . $get_historic['consultDate'] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $get_historic['consultUsername'] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $get_historic['consultDescription'] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $get_historic['consultAmount'] . '</td>';
                if ($get_historic['consultSituation'] === "Pending") {
                    echo '<td><select class="custom-select" name="consultSituation[]"> <option value="Pending" selected>Pending </option> <option value="Confirmed">Confirmed </option><option value="Cancelled">Cancelled </option></select></td>';
                } else if ($get_historic['consultSituation'] === "Confirmed") {
                    echo '<td><select class="custom-select" name="consultSituation[]"> <option value="Pending">Pending </option> <option value="Confirmed" selected>Confirmed </option><option value="Cancelled">Cancelled </option></select></td>';
                } else {
                    echo '<td><select class="custom-select" name="consultSituation[]"> <option value="Pending">Pending </option> <option value="Confirmed">Confirmed </option><option selected value="Cancelled">Cancelled </option></select></td>';
                }
                '</tr>';
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <button type="submit" name="revertbtn" style="background:#009BE1; color:#FEFC5C;" class="btn text-center">Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get into the db connection"?  Put a debugging echo immediately inside the `if` block, and another (with different output) immediately after/outside the `if` block.  Do you see either of them?

Comment: I have done that, only outside the if block I get the echo, inside I don't.

Comment: Well, then your condition isn't being met.  Please update your question to also show the `form` element as well as any JavaScript that might be involved.

Comment: Updated. I dont have any type of javascript involved in this form.

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error on this `'</tr>';`  Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, but the issue ain't even that, since that table and the whole form is in a page and the php is in other. Fixed that missed echo and the problem persists. Enabled error reporting and nothing comes up still.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show (in adminrevertbackend.php)?  You shouldn't have to, but you could try adding `value=1` to your `button` element too.

Comment: `var_dump($POST);` returns NULL.

Comment: `$_POST` not `$POST`

Comment: Oh yeah, misspelled, i'm sorry. it sends a bunch of html arrays from the table.

Comment: Right, but the point is, do you see an entry for "revertbtn" anywhere in there?  If not, then there's some disconnect between what you're showing us and what is actually being run.

Comment: There isn't any entry for "revertbtn".  Does it might have anything to do with the button being in a different div that the table? It should'nt make any difference